# Sorting an array of an array of objects in PHP by key value

Tags: php, arrays, object, sorting, key

Basically I have a setup like the following:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [nid] => 1 [title] => title1 [uid] => 1 [parent] => 0 [weight] => -15 [name] => name1 [value] => 0 )
               [1] => stdClass Object ( [nid] => 2 [title] => title2 [uid] => 1 [parent] => 0 [weight] => -7 [name] => name2 [value] => 100 )
               [2] => stdClass Object ( [nid] => 3 [title] => title3 [uid] => 2 [parent] => 0 [weight] => -1 [name] => name3 [value] => 0 )
               [3] => stdClass Object ( [nid] => 4 [title] => title4 [uid] => 2 [parent] => 0 [weight] => 1 [name] => name4 [value] => 80 )
              )
  )
```

What I need is a way to sort all the arrays inside the parent array by the [value] key in the Object. I've been trying for about 2 days now with usort and different methods but I just can't seem to get my head around it. The [value] key will range anywhere from 0 to 100 and I need all of the arrays sorted in decreasing order (IE: 100 down to 0).

Answer (score 14):

Use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a->value == $b->value) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return $a->value < $b->value ? 1 : -1; // reverse order
  }
}

usort($arr, 'cmp');
```

Comment: In the else clause, just replace the first : with a ?

return $a->value < $b->value ? 1 : -1; // reverse order

Answer (score 4):

100% stolen from the 1st answer on this page.
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php
But this is what I was looking for.

multisort an Array of Objects:

```
example object [$object with array of objects]: (class: test) 
---------------------------------- 

test Object (
  [Artikel] => Array (
      [0] => test Object (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => CCCC
         )
      [1] => test Object (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => AAAA
         )
      [2] => test Object (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => DDDD
         )
      [3] => test Object (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => BBBB
         )
   )
)

---------------------------------- 

Simple PHP function: sort_arr_of_obj()

<?php 
// -------------------------------------- 

/* 
* -------- function arguments -------- 
*   $array ........ array of objects
*   $sortby ....... the object-key to sort by
*   $direction ... 'asc' = ascending
* --------
*/

function sort_arr_of_obj($array, $sortby, $direction='asc') {

    $sortedArr = array();
    $tmp_Array = array();

    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $tmp_Array[] = strtolower($v->$sortby);
    }

    if($direction=='asc'){
        asort($tmp_Array);
    }else{
        arsort($tmp_Array);
    }

    foreach($tmp_Array as $k=>$tmp){
        $sortedArr[] = $array[$k];
    }

    return $sortedArr;

}


// -------------------------------------- 
?>

example call: 
---------------------------------- 

<?php 

$sorted->Artikel = sort_arr_of_obj($object->Artikel,'title','asc');

?>

example result: $sorted (class: test) 
---------------------------------- 

test Object (
  [Artikel] => Array (
      [0] => test Object (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => AAAA
         )
      [1] => test Object (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => BBBB
         )
      [2] => test Object (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => CCCC
         )
      [3] => test Object (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => DDDD
         )

   )
)
```

Comment: Just came across this solution. Works for me too! Thanks :) I did have to tweak it very slightly, as it was returning empty arrays for me though. $tmp_Array[$k] = strtolower($v->$sortby);

Answer (score 3):

A way to do this is to separate the value array from the array of objects, and thus, creating two arrays. You can then use array_multisort to sort the array of objects according to the other array. Here's an example:

```
<?php
$array1 = $objectvalues
$array2 = array(ObjectWithNid1, ObjectWithNid2, ObjectWithNid3, ObjectWithNid4);
array_multisort($array1, $array2);
?>
```

You can use a foreach to loop the array one time and create a new array with the corresponding [value] key:

```
<?php
foreach( $arraywithobjects as $obj )
{
    $objectvalues[] = $obj->getValue();
}
?>
```

This will get the Object's value and insert it into another array which you can use with the multisort.

In the end, your code will look like this:

```
<?php
foreach( $arraywithobjects as $obj )
{
    $objectvalues[] = $obj->getValue();
}
$array2 = array(ObjectWithNid1, ObjectWithNid2, ObjectWithNid3, ObjectWithNid4);
array_multisort($objectvalues, $array2);
?>
```

The first array in the array_multisort field should be the array you're using to sort the second array.

You can also add other sorting method for this. You can read them here: [link text](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $b->value - $a->value;
}

$ary[0] = usort($ary[0], "cmp");
```

In order to sort an array based on anything other than simple value or key, you need to use the `usort` function and supply your own comparison.  Comparison functions must be defined such that if `$a` comes before `$b`, a positive value is returned and a negative one if `$b` comes before `$a` (or zero if they are equal).  As you are comparing based on number values and you want a reverse sort, the simplest way of doing this is to subtract the 'value' of `$a` from the value of `$b`.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe I did something like this using asort() (or asort()). It was in a search function, where I needed to sort a two-dimensional array filled with indices and timestamps.

I'm not sure if it will work in your case, and I did it long ago. Maybe it will get you started though, good luck.