# Arrange array by latest

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 26997
        [product_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1406
                        [type_id] => 1
                        [title] => Shrek - Forever After
                        [cover] => 
                        [coverid] => 0
                        [inserted_by] => 0
                        [inserted_date] => 2011-02-11 14:28:08
                        [status_id] => 1
                    )

            )

        [variable_id] => 1
        [variable_value] => 10
        [master_value] => 
        [released_date] => 2010-12-07
        [price] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 1406
                        [media_format] => BLURAY
                        [price] => 349000
                        [discount] => 5
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 26678
        [product_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1375
                        [type_id] => 1
                        [title] => Shrek Quadrilogy : The Whole Story ( 4 Disc )
                        [cover] => 2066940989de9372d9c39e216430cd5a.jpg
                        [coverid] => 1051
                        [inserted_by] => 0
                        [inserted_date] => 2011-02-07 11:23:21
                        [status_id] => 1
                    )

            )

        [variable_id] => 1
        [variable_value] => 10
        [master_value] => 
        [released_date] => 2011-02-04
        [price] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 1375
                        [media_format] => BLURAY
                        [price] => 999000
                        [discount] => 5
                    )

            )

    )
```

I would like sort by released_date, if you look in the result i want the result to be the newest on top. please help...

Comment: If you fetch that from a database, please sort already in the query using `ORDER BY`. That faster and simpler. Otherwise use `usort` to specify a custom sort function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of an array of objects in PHP by key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414906/sorting-an-array-of-an-array-of-objects-in-php-by-key-value) Here are so many questions regarding multidimensional arrays and sorting: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+multidimensional+array+sort and it the answer is (most often) the same: Use `usort`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the user-callback sort functions are intended for

```
function srtReleased($a, $b) {
    $aDate = strtotime($a['released_date']);
    $bDate = strtotime($b['released_date']);
    if ($aDate == $bDate) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($aDate > $bDate) ? -1 : 1;
}


usort($array, "srtReleased");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something simple like [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms#Bubble_sort) (assuming that your array is not too big, otherwise you'd better use a more efficient sorting algorithm):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($myArray) - 1; $i++) {
  for($j = $i; $j < size(myArray) - 1; $j++) {
    if($myArray[$i]['released_data'] < $myArray[$j]['released_data']) {
      // Swap entries
      $tmp = $myArray[$i + 1];
      $myArray[$i + 1] = $myArray[$i];
      $myArray[$i] = $tmp;
    }
  }
}
```

It basically checks whether the next item is larger than the current item and swap them if that is the case.

You could also use [usort](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), as nikic also suggested. To use it you need to create a compare function, using the same comparison as I showed in the example but wrapped in a function.

Comment: Why not? It is very simple to understand and (as I already mentioned) for small lists there is not much speed loss. It would be a waste of time to implement something complex in such situations. And it would not be too far-fetched to believe that usort() also uses a Bubble Sort algorithm internally...?

Comment: I tried this one and it works, I can't use usort, it says error... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: usort() will only say error if you've got something wrong in your code... show us the code so we can help fix it, rather than simply not using it

Comment: Hehe... my knowledge of different programming languages tend to intersect sometimes... (I will change the example)

Comment: @Veger - all PHP's sorting algorithms are based on a variant of quicksort, rather than on a bubble sort

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use the usort, as nikic suggested. It's much more elegant. Also, I wouldn't recommend using Bubble Sort. It's only advantage is being easier to understand.

Here's a link to an insertion sort someone impolemented in PHP:

http://www.think-lamp.com/2009/08/fastest-insertion-sort-in-php/

If you can adopt this function to sort based on the release date, and use the usort function, you will be in business.

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" means (errors? what?) and show your code... usort() is the right way to do this... now explain your error